# How to find hidden partition of a USB in linux

Tags: partition, usb-drive, fdisk, parted, hdparm

I have a USB, which has a protected partition. I think this USB has hidden partitions, which I can't see them.

`$ fdisk -l /dev/sdb`:

```
You must set cylinders.
You can do this from the extra functions menu.

Disk /dev/sdd: 0 MB, 18432 bytes
8 heads, 63 sectors/track, 0 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 504 * 512 = 258048 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xea168bf5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *           1           1          15+   1  FAT12
Partition 1 has different physical/logical beginnings (non-Linux?):
     phys=(0, 1, 1) logical=(0, 0, 2)
Partition 1 has different physical/logical endings:
     phys=(998, 7, 63) logical=(0, 0, 32
```

---

`$ ls -l /dev/sdd*`:

```
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 48 Jul  4 13:07 /dev/sdd
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 49 Jul  4 13:07 /dev/sdd1
```

---

`$ parted /dev/sdd`:

```
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdd read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdd has been opened read-only.
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdd read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdd has been opened read-only.
```

---

I used `hdparm -r0 /dev/sdd`, too, but **NOTHING HAPPENED!**

**Question:** How can I find hidden partitions and mount them for copying files?

Comment: Try fiddling around with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) (I don't know enough about TestDisk to tell you which commands to try).